# Nested state won't show its ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with UI-router in AngularJS and working with my nested views, I have multiple levels of states, but at one point I cannot trigger my UI-view.
Here is my state definition:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('guest-abstract', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            '@': { templateUrl: 'partials/toolbar',
                    controller: 'BaseController',
                    controllerAs: 'baseCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.home',{
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'choosing': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/home',
              controller: 'choosingController',
              controllerAs: 'chooseCtrl'
          }
        }

    })
    .state('guest-abstract.cinemas',{
        url: '/cinemas',
        resolve: {
            initialData: function(CinemasService){

                    //console.log(CinemasService.loadAllCinemas());
                  return CinemasService.initialCinemasCtrlData(); 
              }
        },
        views: {
            'cinemas': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/cinemas',
              controller: 'CinemasController',
              controllerAs: 'cinemasCtrl'
          }
        }
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.theatres',{
        url: '/theatres',
        resolve: {
            initialData: function(TheatresService){
                 // console.log(TheatresService);
                  return TheatresService.initialTheatresCtrlData();   
              }
        },
        views: {
            'theatres': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/theatres',
              controller: 'TheatresController',
              controllerAs: 'theatresCtrl'
          }
        }   
    })
    .state('success',{
        url: '/success',
        templateUrl: 'partials/successMessage',
        controller: 'UserController',
        controllerAs: 'sCtrl'
    })
    .state('badToken',{
        url: '/badToken',
        templateUrl: 'partials/badtoken',

    })
    .state('login',{
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .state('registration',{
        url: '/registration',
        templateUrl: 'partials/registration',
        controller: 'UserController',
        controllerAs: 'regCtrl'
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.profile-abstract', {
        url: '/:username',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'profilePage': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/profilePage'

          }
        }   
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.profile-abstract.profile-overview', {
        url: '/overview',
        resolve: {
            initialData: ['$stateParams', 'UserService',function($stateParams, UserService){
                  return UserService.getUser($stateParams.username);   
              }]
        },
        views: {
            'overview': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/profileOverview',
              controller: 'ProfileController',
              controllerAs: 'profCtrl'
          }
        }  
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.profile-abstract.profile-abstract-friends', {
        url: '/friends',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'friends': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/friends',
          }
        }  
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.profile-abstract.profile-abstract-friends.friends-list', {
        url: '/friendsList',
        resolve: {
            initialData: ['$stateParams', 'FriendsService',function($stateParams, FriendsService){
                console.log("Usao je u resolve");
                console.log($stateParams.username);
                console.log(FriendsService.initialFriendsCtrlData($stateParams.username));
                return FriendsService.initialFriendsCtrlData($stateParams.username);   
              }]
        },
        views: {
            'friendsList@guest-abstract.profile-abstract.profile-abstract-friends': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/friendsList',
              controller: 'FriendsController',
              controllerAs: 'friendsCtrl'
          }
        }  
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.profile-abstract.profile-abstract-friends.friends-search', {
        url: '/friendsSearch',
        resolve: {
            initialData: ['$stateParams', 'FriendsService',function($stateParams, FriendsService){
                console.log("Usao je u resolve");
                console.log($stateParams.username);
                console.log(FriendsService.initialFriendsCtrlData($stateParams.username));
                return FriendsService.initialFriendsCtrlData($stateParams.username);   
              }]
        },
        views: {
            'friendsSearch': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/friendsSearch',
              controller: 'FriendsController',
              controllerAs: 'friendsCtrl'
          }
        }  
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.settings-abstract', {
        url: '/settings',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'settingsPage': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/settingsPage'

          }
        }   
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.settings-abstract.general', {
        url: '/general',
        resolve: {
            initialData: ['$stateParams', 'UserService',function($stateParams, UserService){
                  return UserService.getUser($stateParams.username);   
              }]
        },
        views: {
            'general': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/generalSettings',
              controller: 'ProfileController',
              controllerAs: 'settingsCtrl'
          }
        },
        params: {
            username:null
        }  
    })
    .state('guest-abstract.settings-abstract.security', {
        url: '/security',
        resolve: {
            initialData: ['$stateParams', 'UserService',function($stateParams, UserService){
                  return UserService.getUser($stateParams.username);   
              }]
        },
        views: {
            'general': {
              templateUrl: 'partials/securitySettings',
              controller: 'ProfileController',
              controllerAs: 'securityCtrl'
          }
        },
        params: {
            username: null
        }  
    })
```

But when I put state like this it renders fine

```
 .state('friendsList2',{
        url: '/friendsList2',
        templateUrl: 'partials/friendsList',
        controller: 'FriendsController',
        controllerAs: 'friendsCtrl',
        resolve: {
            initialData: ['$stateParams', 'FriendsService',function($stateParams, FriendsService){
                console.log("Usao je u resolve");
                console.log($stateParams.username);
                console.log(FriendsService.initialFriendsCtrlData($stateParams.username));
                return FriendsService.initialFriendsCtrlData($stateParams.username);   
              }]
        },
        params: {
            username: null
        } 
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}]);
```

In my index.ftl I have just:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

In next state I have:

```
     <div ui-view='choosing'></div>
   <div ui-view='cinemas'></div>
   <div ui-view='theatres'></div>
   <div ui-view='profilePage'></div>
   <div ui-view='settingsPage'></div>
```

In state guest-abstract.profile-abstract I have:

```
<div ui-view='overview'></div>
<div ui-view='friends'></div>
```

And in state:

'guest-abstract.profile-abstract.profile-abstract-friends'

I have `<div iu-view="friendsList"></div>`

and that is where UI-view is not triggered, but when I made state without parents with that templateUrl and controllers it worked perfectly.

It is bugging me for several hours if anyone could help me I would appreciate it!! For any other information, I am here, thanks.

ps, I have tried every possible combination of naming.

Comment: You wrote `<div iu-view="friendsList"></div>`  instead `ui-view` ?

Comment: Yeah it was a typo. It took me 4h to realize that, due to exhaustion and lack of sleep. Thanks.

Comment: Haha no problem !